# MVC2 :: How do I *USE* a Custom IIdentity Class?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization, iprincipal, iidentity

I am trying to store a whole truckload of information about a user from a webservice.  As this is information about the currently authenticated user, I thought it would make sense to store that information in a custom IIdentity implementation.

The custom `MagicMembershipProvider.GetUser(string id, bool userIsOnline)` calls the webservice and returns a `MagicMembershipUser` instance with all the fields populated (department, phone number, other employee info).

The custom membership provider and custom membership user both work fine.

***What* and *where* is the best way to put the membership user information into the `IPrincipal User` object that is accessible in every controller?**

I have been trying to wrap my brain around the program flow of security with IIdentity, IPrincipal and Role authorization in an MVC2 application -- but I'm really struggling here and could use some mentoring.  There a Internet Ton of articles about the parts, but not much about the whole.

## Edit

My best guess so far is to assign the `HttpContext.Current.User` in the `FormsAuthenticationService`:

```
public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) 
    throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

  try
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    MagicMembershipUser magicUser = _provider.GetUser("", false) 
      as MagicMembershipUser;
    MagicIdentity identity = new MagicIdentity(userName, magicUser);
    GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    throw;
  }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What and where is the best way to put the membership user information into the IPrincipal User object that is accessible in every controller?

In a custom [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) filter implementation. You could override the [AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore.aspx) method and call the base method and if it returns true query your membership provider and inject the custom magic identity into the context.

Example:

```
public class MagicAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var magicUser = _provider.GetUser(username, false) as MagicMembershipUser;
            var identity = new MagicIdentity(username, magicUser);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
            httpContext.User = principal;
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is decorate your base controller with the `[MagicAuthorize]` attribute.

Comment: I notice there is no instantiation for _provider - why is that?

Comment: @ScottSEA, this `_provider` variable could be anything which allows you to retrieve authenticated user information.

Comment: So would it be safe to instantiate it here in this method?

... and for some reason I am getting an error that says there is "no suitable method found to override" for AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)

Comment: That's strange. I have no idea. If you press F12 over AuthorizeAttribute do you see the method?

Comment: Upon some searching, I have found that it might have something to do with the fact that I have the MagicAuthorizeAttribute class in a Class Library Project (I'm trying to make this functionality reusable throughout the company) - but I have not a clue how to fix it.  I do have a `using` directive for System.Web and System.Web.Mvc - when I type "override" intellisense pops up a box of `AuthorizeAttribute` methods for me to choose from. (I am using .net 4.0 framework)

Comment: I ended up having to add a reference to `System.Web.Abstractions` to my Class Project.